# how to reterive the value present within the brackets

Tags: text-processing

I need to retrieve the number which is present in bracket only with total comamnd line.

For ex:

```
$ cat exa.lg
02:57:25 BROKER  : Unable to open errno =. (1295)
02:57:25 BROKER  1: Unable to open (45)
02:57:25 BROKER  1: Unable to open 999. (13)
02:57:25 BROKER  : Unable to open 1295, (1098)
```

I need to get the information for error number `1295` which is in the brackets, not in the command line (`BROKER  : Unable to open 1295`)

I tried with this:

```
cat exa.lg | awk -F '[)(]' '{print $2}' | grep -E '1295|13' exa.lg
02:57:25 BROKER  : Unable to open errno =. (1295)
02:57:25 BROKER  1: Unable to open 999. (13)
02:57:25 BROKER  : Unable to open 1295, (1098)
```

But I am getting both `1295` numbers (including the one in `02:57:25 BROKER  : Unable to open 1295`).

I want to fetch only `02:57:25 BROKER  : Unable to open errno =. (1295)`.

How can I do this?

Comment: You'd get fewer downvotes and thus draw more attention to your question if you made an effort to format it properly and check your spelling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the parentheses in your regular expression. You need to escape them since they have special meaning in regexp.

```
grep -E '\((1295|13)\)' exa.lg
```

Comment: I tried it 
Its working fine.

Thanks all for quick support........

Comment: You should accept the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simple ***awk*** solution:

```
awk '/\((1295|13)\)/{ print }' exa.lg
```

The output:

```
02:57:25 BROKER  : Unable to open errno =. (1295)
02:57:25 BROKER  1: Unable to open 999. (13)
```

---

- `/\((1295|13)\)/` - matches either `(1295)` or `(13)` within a record. (May be also presented as `/(1295)|(13)/`)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to print all lines that contain either a `13` or a `1295` in parentheses. If so, you can do something like:

```
$ grep -E '\(1295|13\)' exa.lg
02:57:25 BROKER  : Unable to open errno =. (1295)
02:57:25 BROKER  1: Unable to open 999.
```

The `cat` of your original command isn't needed since both `awk` and `grep` can take a file name as input. Also, your `awk` is pointless since your `grep` is being run on the file (`grep exa.lg`) and not on the output of the awk.

Answer (score 0):

`cat input | grep ".=" > output`

or

`cat input | grep "errno" > output`

and you will have:

```
02:57:25 BROKER  : Unable to open errno =. (1295)
```

but you have to be sure that all those type of lines have these unique identifiers (i.e. none of the other lines have these words/symbols):
"errno" or "=."